# Calculation Equivalent Resistance In A Circuit With resistances connected in a circle

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance

I am having trouble in finding the equivalent resistance between the terminals 'a' and 'b' in the following circuit:

[image]

Please can anyone explain to me how to solve such problems.

Thank You!

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Comment: In this case all the resistances are in parallel so it's easy. In general use [Kirchoff's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_circuit_laws) and [the Y-$\Delta$ transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Y-%CE%94_transform).

Comment: You often find with this sort of problem that redrawing the circuit in a different way will help.  Also in some circuits look sor symmetry and nodes which are at the same potential which can therefore be connected with a wire.

Answer (score 1):

In such circuit see that all resistance at rim have same potential, since no resistance reduced it.

At rim all have same potential as that at $a$.
At center all have same potential as that at $b$

So, all have same potential difference $V_{a} - V_{b}$

Same potential difference means that they are connected in parallel.